# Yii session storage, lifetime and cookies

Tags: php, session, cookies, yii

Working with the Yii framework in the config-file session storaged is handled as follows:

```
        'session' => array(
        //'sessionName' => 'SomeSession',
        'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
        'connectionID' => 'SomeConnection',
        'autoCreateSessionTable' => false,
        'sessionTableName' => 'SomeTable',
        'autoStart' => 'false',
        'cookieMode' => 'only',
        'useTransparentSessionID' => false,
        'timeout' => CSESSIONTIMEOUT,
        'cookieParams' => array(
            'path' => '/',
            'domain' => '.somedomain.extension',
            'expire' => time()+5256000,
            'lifetime' => time()+5256000,
            //'httpOnly' => true,
        ),
    ),
```

So as you see sessions are stored in a table in a database with a given lifetime. But if I check the stored sessions in the database they are not stored with the given lifetime they are stored with a lifetime of a year.

The only thing I can find in our application that has a lifetime of a year are the cookies. For example like this:

```
setcookie("cookie_name", $someValue, time()+31536000, "/", "somedomain");
```

What is confusing for me are the cookies in our application. Could it be possible that this overrides the Yii session storage config?

*UPDATE*

I also came across this line of code

```
$_SESSION['POLL_'.$idPoll.'somekey'] = strtotime("now");
```

And that line of code inserted a session record in the database. But that record also has an lifetime of a year. How is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [timeout](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHttpSession#timeout-detail) param to config like this:

```
'session' => array(
        'class' => 'CDbHttpSession',
        'timeout' => 5256000,
        // ...
```

Comment: The above constance is defined but I will try your suggestion

Comment: @PimD1988 I checked it. In table **Session** sets expire value +  5256000

Comment: Yes but the point is that the sessions are stored for a longer periode than defined, a year actually which is not what I want to happen.

Comment: @PimD1988 ok. Try to insert next row to any action of controller: `echo gmdate("Y-m-d", time()+5256000); die();`. What do you see? In my case result: `2016-02-17`

Answer (score 0):

```
Try Cookies Like this : -   
 if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
           $cookieUsername = new CHttpCookie('phoenix_admin_username', $_POST['LoginForm']['username']);
           $cookiePassword = new CHttpCookie('phoenix_admin_password', base64_encode($_POST['LoginForm']['password']));
           $cookieUsername->expire = time() + 604800;
           $cookiePassword->expire = time() + 604800;
           Yii::app()->request->cookies['phoenix_admin_username'] = $cookieUsername;
             Yii::app()->request->cookies['phoenix_admin_password'] = $cookiePassword;
 } 

  ////////////Check like this//////////////

    if(isset(Yii::app()->request->cookies['phoenix_admin_username'])){
        $model->username = Yii::app()->request->cookies['phoenix_admin_username']->value;
        $model->password = base64_decode(Yii::app()->request->cookies['phoenix_admin_password']->value);
    }else{
        $model->username = "";
        $model->password = "";
    }
```